# Fastest way to check the records if exists in the SQL table

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have hundreds of thousands of records in my SQL table. If between particular data, if no record is present, it takes so much time to inform us. Currently, I am using this query to check if record exists.

```
select TOP 1 1 AS getRowCount 
from MYTable 
where ID IN ('3','5','2','4','1') 
AND (
      datewithTime >= '2015-01-01 07:00:00' 
     AND datewithTime < '2016-01-01 07:00:00'
    )
```

In the above query, I am getting the record of 1 year, but records are not present in this time limit. But it is taking too much time to respond. Is there any other way that can show if data exists in the table for this particular time interval ?

Will LINQ perform better ?

Comment: What's the execution plan, have you added indexes etc?

Comment: "Will LINQ perform better?" - no. If you're using LINQ to SQL, then it has to be translated into SQL anyway. If you're using LINQ to objects, then it would have to retrieve everything in the table first, and then start looking for matching data.

Comment: Looking at this, you might want to add index on ID and datewithTime columns. Also, I believe the data type for datewithTime column is DateTime

Comment: I have used created primary key & indexes on the ID column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, You should use the EXISTS statement instead of selecting top 1:

```
SET @getRowCount = EXISTS(select 1
       from MYTable 
       where ID IN ('3','5','2','4','1') 
       AND datewithTime >= '2015-01-01 07:00:00' 
       AND datewithTime < '2016-01-01 07:00:00'
)
```

Second, you should check the execution plan to see if you can improve performance by adding indices or altering existing indices.

**update**

Sorry, I wasn't paying enough attention to what I'm writing.
Exists returns a boolean value, but sql server does not have a boolean data type, this is why you get the incorrect syntax error.

Here is the correct syntax:

```
DECLARE  @getRowCount bit = 0

IF EXISTS(select 1
       from MYTable 
       where ID IN ('3','5','2','4','1') 
       AND datewithTime >= '2015-01-01 07:00:00' 
       AND datewithTime < '2016-01-01 07:00:00'
) SET @getRowCount = 1

SELECT @getRowCount
```

Comment: Error occurred `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXISTS'`

Comment: This solution is too faster than my previous one. My syntax was taking 40 seconds to to do the same job, but this one taking not even a second. Thanks

Comment: That's because when you are selecting `top 1` you force sql server to actually select (and possibly sort) data, while when you are using `exists`, all the sql server has to do is evaluating the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

First of all add indexes to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_TableName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TableName_datewithTime ] ON TableName
(
    datewithTime ASC
)
GO
```

Then change your query to this:

```
if exists(select * from TableName
          where ID in ('3','5','2','4','1') and
                datewithTime >= '2015-01-01 07:00:00' and 
                datewithTime < '2016-01-01 07:00:00')
    select 1 as DataExists
else
    select 0 as DataExists
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I got my answer.